# IIF statement value fails to display accordingly in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

In SSRS, when I use a basic if statement like this:

```
IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = TRUE, 1, 0)
```

When I run the report, it gives me `TRUE` or `FALSE` instead of 1 or 0 as the value in each cell. What could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the 1 and 0 in quotes to make them string values. i.e .. "1", "0")

Answer (score 0):

=IIF(Fields!FieldName.Value = TRUE,Fields!FieldName.Value= "1",FieldName.Value= "0")